# WHy isn't my PHP code working?

Tags: php, html

I'm just wondering why this code isn't working, Thanks in advance. I'm new, so please don't hate me for it.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <h1> Hey! </h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
        ran = rand(0, 5);
            if ($ran != 2){
            echo "hi";
            }
            else{
                echo "wow";
            }
      ?>

    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this ain't php. thats html

Comment: What happens when you run it? output?done

Comment: Missing a `$`.  `ran = rand(0, 5);` needs to be `$ran = rand(0, 5);`

Comment: replace ran = rand(0, 5); to $ran = rand(0, 5);

Comment: Does the file have a .php extension instead of .html?

Comment: Check whether your file is saved under the php extension, if you are running this in some kind of a php server. If you are new to PHP, I recommend you to study some sites or a book about the php. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp would be a good place to start.

Comment: `<head>
  <h1> Hey! </h1>
  </head>` that's not even valid HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have PHP installed on your computer? You cannot just run PHP files from your browser, you have to have something like XAMPP or WAMP installed, or at the very least, PHP installed and your paths set to allow your browser to process PHP.

So long as you have the ability to view PHP files in your browser, your file extension is ".php", and you add the "$" before "ran", there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Download XAMPP from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html. It's installable and includes everything you need to work with PHP locally.

Comment: can I use adobe dreamweaver instead?

Comment: No. You would still need PHP installed. Sorry but there is simply no way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ran = rand(0, 5);
```

change it to

```
$ran = rand(0, 5);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :/

Comment: What is the output when you run the script..?done

Comment: I run it with firefox, but the output is just "Hey!"

Comment: Does the file you running have .php at the end of is it .html..? because if its .html at the end it wont reach the php code. make sure it ends with .php extension...done

Comment: It was html, but I changed it to .php. It still has the same output

Comment: Are using localhost as the local server?done